# Publish a .NET 8 Blazor WebAssembly standalone app for static site deployment

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-8.0

Currently I'm using blazor webassembly with .NET 7.
I've created my .NET 7 project with:

```
dotnet new blazorwasm
```

Then if you do a:

```
dotnet publish
```

You will end up with a publish folder containing something like this:

[image: blazor7 publish]

Which is hostable on a static server, because it contains an index.html and is all webassembly. This works.

Now I want to do exactly the same in .NET 8. The templates changed, and I think for what I want I need this:

```
dotnet new blazor -int WebAssembly
```

But when I publish this, I end up with a publish folder like this:

[image: Blazor8 publish]

Which because it does not contain an index.html, is never going to work on static hosting.

I've read the whole host and deploy guide from MS https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/host-and-deploy/webassembly but I fail to find anything mentioning creating a custom index.html or something like that.

So I'm not sure which part I'm missing, but to me this unfindable and I sure could use some help here..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I guess that with the statement from here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/release-notes/aspnetcore-8.0?view=aspnetcore-8.0:

> We've introduced a new Blazor project template: the Blazor Web App template. The new template provides a single starting point for using Blazor components to build any style of web UI.

'Any style of web UI' does NOT mean a Standalone WebAssembly Blazor app. At least not without modifying it or something.

Turns out that you can (and must, I guess) use:

```
dotnet new blazorwasm
```

To create Standalone Blazor 8 WebAssembly app.

Answer (score 0):

> I've read the whole host and deploy guide from MS ... but I fail to find anything mentioning creating a custom index.html or something like that.

The *Blazor Web App* [blazor] template builds various configurations based on a ASPNetCore hosting solution.  This includes server side pre-rendering for WASM.

If you want a Standalone project, use the *Blazor Web Assembly StandAlone App* [blazorwasm] template.